# SSIS Excel connection challenges

Tags: c#, excel, ssis, ssis-2012

I was able to complete my task with out any problem if excel file is open

If Excel file is open then no error import task works perfectly.

If Excel file is closed, i get below error

Failed to acquire connection "Excel Connection Manager 4". Connection may not be configured correctly or you may not have the right permissions on this connection.

Any thoughts on how to handle

Comment: have you read the `MSDN Docmentation` on this perhaps you have something configured incorrectly here is the link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms139836.aspx

Comment: It works fine for bunch of excel files without any problem. I loop thru different excel files in a folder(.xlsx files)  set connections & properties programmatically.

Comment: ok so perhaps the Excel Connection Manager is the issue or you have a `COMObjectRelease` issue going on.. I am still a bit confused on your issue then.. can you verify this using the TaskManager and seeing if it releases all instances when running those Excel files..? also is there custom code that you can add to the `SSIS` package in code behind..?

Comment: 1. I'm not sure about COMObjectRelease issue. 2. Task Manager didn't release all instances so i manually released them all and i did re-run the ssis task with same error msg. 3. Yes i can add custom code but not sure what to add. Remember SSIS task will work fine if EXCEL IS OPEN, I got issues with closed excel files and that too only on certain excel files not sure why that difference

Answer (score 1):

```
Try to specify these extra parameters in your Excel connection string: 
  Mode=Read; ReadOnly=True
 Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=filename; Extended Properties="EXCEL 8.0;HDR=YES; Mode=Read; ReadOnly =True;"
```

and try this also :

It sounds like there is an Excel connection string in your package which is not valid for some reason. Try:

1. Opening your package (.DTSX file) in an XML editor (I use XML Marker - its nice and simple)
2. Search for the 'Dynamic Excel Connection Manager' entry.
3. See if you can identify the connection string in there.
4. Fix it it and save